# I have been trying to install sqldeveloper on ubuntu 22.04 but am getting error while using dpkg

Tags: ubuntu, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have installed .rpm file for sqldeveloper installation and have converted it to .deb file using the following command as there was error while using alien:

```
sudo fpm -s rpm -t deb sqldeveloper-22.2.0-173.2018.noarch.rpm
```

I am trying to install the .deb file by using this command:

```
sudo dpkg --install sqldeveloper_22.2.0-173.2018_all.deb
```

But I am getting this error:

> dpkg: error processing archive sqldeveloper_22.2.0-173.2018_all.deb
> (--install):
>   parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/control' near
> line 7 package 'sqldeveloper':
>   'Depends' field, invalid package
> name '/bin/sh': must start with an alphanumeric character
>  Errors
> were encountered while processing:
> sqldeveloper_22.2.0-173.2018_all.deb

Is there any way I could install this?

Answer (score -1):

SQL Developer is available as `zip` file also and you can extract it on every desired place. Here is [download link](https://www.oracle.com/database/sqldeveloper/technologies/download/). Search for other platforms.